# Predicting bit error rates for RF communications

Tags: rf, antenna, signal-integrity

I am trying to estimate what the approximate bit error rate for a given antenna configuration would be.

Specifically, suppose I have two parabolic dish antennas pointed at each other.  If they are separated by a range $R$, for a given transmit power $P$ and at a given frequency $f$ with bandwidth $\Delta f$ (supposed we are in Ka band), what would be the bit error rate?

Even better, what is a good resource to look up this information myself?

Comment: On earth? Pointing at space? Raised up on masts? Try https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCUQFjABahUKEwiYq7OmwfTIAhVEkQ8KHRnoDuM&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffaculty.ksu.edu.sa%2Fzhejaz%2FEE%2520423%2FBook_Cambridge_Essentials%2520of%2520Radio%2520W%2520Propag_ED_2008.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGOeNdlnkJU2haq9SdEJ3eKWa8xJg&sig2=6_PkY3i60_yINDOAG4x9lQ&cad=rja - it's called "essentials of radio wave propagation" and has an interesting section starting on page 14.

Comment: @Andyaka Awesome thanks, I will check out this book.

Answer (score 1):

The BER (bit error rate) can be ANYTHING ! What is BER ? It is the number of bits that are received incorrectly per so many bits. For example 10 ppm (parts per million) meaning 10 in 1 million bits is wrong.

The parameters you specify have no direct relation to the BER. I can build two systems according to a range, transmit power, frequency and bandwidth specified by you. System A will have a BER of 1 ppm and system B will have a BER of 1000 ppm. How can that be ? Well, you do not specify the datarate, modulation type or signal noise ratio so by choosing all of these parameters to my liking I can build system A and system B.

The parameters you specify relate more to the way how the signal (containing the data) is transported. It does not say anything about the signal I'm transporting, how it's modulated, what the datarate is, what signal noise is required etc. And it's these parameters that actually matter for the BER.